# UINavigationcontroller pushViewController not working to get next Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uikit, uistoryboard

I red nearly all the help which is provided, and i'm still confused. I have simple project in Xcode4.2 with sotoryboard. There i have Navigationcontroller and two Viewcontroler (one, two). If i'm trying to get from one to two with pushViewController its break down. Where is my problem. If i have the Navigationcontroler in my storyboard i shouldn't have problem to access it and use it, is it right? I don't won modal window application i use something like story board where the user can move back and front without lose the controls data. How should i do it right.

thanks for any help I'm new to apple developing :)

The only code :

```
- (IBAction)Next:(id)sender{
    two* myNext = [[two alloc] initWithNibName:@"two" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self navigationController]);
    NSLog(@"%d", [[[self navigationController] viewControllers] count]);
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:myNext animated:YES];
//    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:myNext animated:YES];
//    [myNext release];
}
```

Comment: what is there in logs that you have logged?

Comment: Ok i figured that out :). Solution in the main question.

Comment: You should add the solution as an answer and then accept it so that it won't forever show up as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to change the initialize UIViewController because of using storyboard you can't use initWithNibName. You have to use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier which use identifier property of UIViewController. The identifier property can by set in the sotryboard.

```
ViewController* myNext = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Next"];
```